# codeigniter session values lost on second page

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have lengthy search form and i am trying to keep the form values in session. I use codeigniter pagination, so i need to store the values entered in the search form in the session (i am trying to avoid storing them in the database)

This problem bother me couple of days and i am unable to solve it. Here is the code. For the sake of clarification i provide the comments for each line of my code:

```
    // my submit button named search_button has been clicked
if ($this->input->post('search_button')) {

    // all the values from the form are stored in array
    $formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

    // i assign the values of $formValues array to session
    $this->session->set_userdata('formValues', $formValues);

    // i store the values in local variable
    $mySessData = $this->session->userdata('formValues');

    // i count the values of the $formValues to be sure how many fields i get back
    // reason for that is that my form is built dynamically
    // returns 19 if the form has been submitted. 
    // when i submit the form, i get 19
    echo "Count of form values is now: " . count($formValues);

    // i print the $formValues array, to be sure that it return the form values
    // and yes, it does if the form has been submitted.
    // see the $formValues returns section bellow to see what is returned
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($formValues);
    echo "</pre>";

    // i print my local variable to ensure that variable $mySessData is not empty
    // see the section $mySessData retruns (1) to see returned values
    echo "Confirm that sess data has been set up";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mySessData);
    echo "</pre>";
} else {

    // else, means that form has not been submitted but that controller has been called from the next link
    // in the pagination links. This always return empty array, that is nothing...
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mySessData);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

If the form has been submitted, the $formValues returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
    [search_button] => Submit‚
)
```

My variable $mySessData returns the very same dataif the form has been submitted:

```
Array
(
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
    [search_button] => Submit‚
)
```

And on the end, if i click on pagination link

```
 $config['base_url'] = site_url('/searchresults/display/'.$limit.'/');
```

, which point to the same controller and same method, well..i get an empty array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: This is just an idea and may not be correct. You may need to store your CI sessions in a DB table because each cookie can only store 4kb of data. Another thing to look at is, are you sure the code is going through the correct if/else section. If for instance it was going through the `if` part then the session would be reset because of the way you are assigning the `formValues` session.

Comment: how would you re-write that if statement? i am running out of ideas after so long being stuck in this code...about the 4kb limit..in that case, i guess that values will not be stored in the session in the first part of the if if that was the problem

Comment: in the application/config/config.php there is an option to turn DB sessions on, the session db table SQL can be found in the CI manual.

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be better if use method="get" in your form. posting your form with get instead of post would be more preferable in case of search form as u wont need to maintain any session and no need of storing values in database also. you can easily access a feild anytime using

`$this ->input->get('fild_name');`

You can optimize your code this way and you dont need to maintain session variables as you will always have the search feild valies in your url. Using session another problem is with unsetting the session variable.

I personally dont think that creating a session variable just to maintain pagination is not a good idea.Moreover in a search form there is no need of security so you can send your form using "get" insted of "post"

Comment: i am trying to implement the db solution now, and i will see if that will work for me...thanks anyway...too bad that get option never cross my mind before...we will see

Comment: yes it happens ..actually i faced the same issues a couple of days ago. No problem let me know if your idea works .. :)

Comment: Hi. I tried the db solution and it didn't worked for me. I also try your solution, but i get empty result set. Do you have 15 min to try this on chat?

Comment: sorry i am offline for today.. will be avalable tomorrow at 2:00pm (IST). Please let me know.

Comment: hi. i will drop you a line here...if i don't solve it until then. i will post here in any case.